# How does JavaScript's DOM updating algorithm work?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, dom

Here's a simple DOM playground that logs the state whenever a button is clicked:

```js
const parent = document.querySelector('#parent');
const [div1, div2, div3] = parent.children;
const [removeDiv2, addDiv4, reset] =
  document.querySelectorAll('button');

const div4 = document.createElement('div');
div4.classList.add('children');
div4.id = 'div4';
div4.textContent = 'div4';


logCurrentState();


removeDiv2.addEventListener('click', () => {
  parent.removeChild(div2);
  logCurrentState();
});


addDiv4.addEventListener('click', () => {
  parent.insertBefore(div4, div3);
  logCurrentState();
});


reset.addEventListener('click', () => {
  parent.replaceChildren(div1, div2, div3);
  console.clear();
  logCurrentState();
})

function logCurrentState() {
  console.log(
    [...parent.children].map(
      child => ({
        previous: child.previousElementSibling?.id ?? null,
        current: child.id,
        next: child.nextElementSibling?.id ?? null
      })
    )
  );
}
```

```css
.children {
  padding: 1em;
  font-family: monospace;
}

#div1 {
  background: #ef6461;
}

#div2 {
  background: #e4b363;
}

#div3 {
  background: #e8e9eb;
}

#div4 {
  background: #e0dfd5;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>

<div id="parent">
  <div class="children" id="div1">div1</div>
  <div class="children" id="div2">div2</div>
  <div class="children" id="div3">div3</div>
</div>

<button>Remove div2</button>
<button>Add div4</button>
<button>Reset</button>
```

As one can see, JS updates each element's relevant properties (e.g. `.nextElementSibling`, `previousElementSibling`, `.children`, etc.) immediately when a DOM-modifying method (e.g. `.removeChild()`, `.insertBefore()`, `.replaceWith()`, etc.) is called.

For convenience, here's an excerpt from the logs:

```js
// Original
[
  { previous: null, current: 'div1', next: 'div2' },
  { previous: 'div1', current: 'div2', next: 'div3' },
  { previous: 'div2', current: 'div3', next: null }
]

// After removing div2
[
  { previous: null, current: 'div1', next: 'div3' },
  { previous: 'div1', current: 'div3', next: null }
]
```

How does the engine do this under the hood? Is it standardized by the spec or implementation-specific? What is the complexity of the algorithm in question?

Comment: This is about how browsers work, not really about how JavaScript works.

Comment: ...hence the second question: "*Is it standardized by the spec or implementation-specific?*"

Comment: Right, what I mean is "the spec" is not the JavaScript language spec, it's one or another of the W3C specifications for the DOM etc.

Comment: If you pick one of those properties, say `previousElementSibling`, and check the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/previousElementSibling) page, you'll find it has a section for specifications, and links the [DOM standard](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-dom-nondocumenttypechildnode-previouselementsibling%E2%91%A1). If you haven't already, looking at these might be a good place to start, and might lead you to other resources that will help answer your question.

Comment: @David784 I have read those, and even tried to look at [v8's code repo](https://github.com/v8/v8), but [they are C++ to me](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greek_to_me).

Answer (score 1):

> JS updates each element's relevant properties

Not really. JS does trigger the update, but it (generally) doesn't do the update by itself.

In most user agents the DOM doesn't live within the JS engine, the JS engine just sends instructions to the DOM engine through an API that is defined at https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/

Stuff like `Element#previousElementSibling` in the JS world are getters, like you could define one yourself e.g with

```js
const obj = {
  get myProp() { /* execute something and return a value */ }
};
```

except that here it executes internal code that will call methods of the DOM engine, which will ultimately convert the DOM value back to a JS value that the JS engine can work with.

The standards do no define how a DOM value is converted to or from a JS value, so this would be left to the implementation, but they do define how a value is converted between JS and [*infra*](https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/) or [*Web IDL*](https://webidl.spec.whatwg.org/), which do define the data types used by the specifications, and which ensures that all (complying) implementations will expose the same behavior.

---

[Some readings about a particular implementation (Chromium + V8)](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/third_party/blink/renderer/bindings/core/v8/V8BindingDesign.md#DOM-wrappers-and-worlds).
Special mention to [jsdom](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom) and their JS implementation, where [you can see](https://github.com/jsdom/jsdom/blob/e5b8e8afdebee816862584cb7d45bdc6f86d54af/lib/jsdom/living/nodes/NonDocumentTypeChildNode-impl.js#L16) how they also use a getter to implement `previousElementSibling` et al.

Comment: jsdom's implementation seems to be O(n). Is V8's the same?